# Why does casting net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker to android.widget.NumberPicker work?

Tags: android

I have an app using `NumberPicker`s. Since the app supports older versions of Android, where no `NumberPicker` widget had been available yet, I have to use an [external library](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker).

In my XML layout `numberpicker_dialog.xml`, I define the `NumberPicker` like this:

```
<net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/interval_picker_1"
    ... />
```

Then in the code of my activity, I have:

```
import net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker;

private View intervalPickerDialogBody;
private NumberPicker intervalPicker1;
private android.widget.NumberPicker api11_intervalPicker1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    intervalPickerDialogBody = getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.numberpicker_dialog, null);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // the casting in question happens here
        api11_intervalPicker1 = (android.widget.NumberPicker)
                 intervalPickerDialogBody.findViewById(R.id.interval_picker_1);
    } else {
        intervalPicker1 = (NumberPicker)
                 intervalPickerDialogBody.findViewById(R.id.interval_picker_1);
    }

}
```

It works, and really on Honeycomb and newer, `android.widget.NumberPicker` is used, on older versions, `net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker` is used.

But now that I am writing a thesis about the app using this, I wonder:

1. Why does casting `net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker` from the XML layout to `android.widget.NumberPicker` work when they in reality are different classes?
2. How come that only this casting makes the device use `android.widget.NumberPicker` on Honeycomb and newer when the `NumberPicker` that's in the XML layout is actually the one from the exetrnal library? When is an instance of `android.widget.NumberPicker` ever created?

The fact that `android.widget.NumberPicker` is used on Honeycomb and newer is supported by the fact the second line of the forecoming code snippet equals `true` on my 4.0.3 phone.

```
View tmp = intervalPickerDialogBody.findViewById(R.id.interval_picker_1);
tmp instanceof android.widget.NumberPicker // pseudocode
```

(Thank you, Jules, this is a much better proof than the striked one with the arrows. :))

<strike>If anyone wonders how I know that `android.widget.NumberPicker` is actually used on Honeycomb and newer, it's because `net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker` doesn't display arrows above and below the `NumberPicker` as it was backported from 4.2 where the arrows have been removed. And when I try it on my device running 4.0.3, the arrows are there even though if it should display `net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker`, they wouldn't be.</strike>

I hope the question is understandable. Thanks for elaborating on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.  It seems to be because of what appears to me to be a bug in LayoutInflater.  Here's the code used to decide what View class is used for a particular XML tag:

```
public final View createView(String name, String prefix, AttributeSet attrs)
        throws ClassNotFoundException, InflateException {
    Constructor constructor = sConstructorMap.get(name);
    Class clazz = null;

    try {
        if (constructor == null) {
            // Class not found in the cache, see if it's real, and try to add it
            clazz = mContext.getClassLoader().loadClass(
                    prefix != null ? (prefix + name) : name);

            if (mFilter != null && clazz != null) {
                boolean allowed = mFilter.onLoadClass(clazz);
                if (!allowed) {
                    failNotAllowed(name, prefix, attrs);
                }
            }
            constructor = clazz.getConstructor(mConstructorSignature);
            sConstructorMap.put(name, constructor);
        }
        ...
```

Before this is called, the prefix (i.e. everything up to and including the last dot in the tag name) is separated out and put into the prefix parameter, so for your XML, the call is:

```
createView ("NumberPicker", "net.simonvt.numberpicker.", ...);
```

This means that when the createView method checks in the cache for a previously-used constructor, *as long as a NumberPicker has been used before* it will return the system NumberPicker.

As a corollary to my belief that this is a bug, I would modify your code above to safeguard against the possibility that a future variant of Android will fix the bug by testing which type of object is returned by findViewById using the instanceof operator, rather than your current version number test, i.e.:

```
View tmp = intervalPickerDialogBody.findViewById(R.id.interval_picker_1);
if (tmp instanceof android.widget.NumberPicker) { // Note 1 below
    api11_intervalPicker1 = (android.widget.NumberPicker)
             intervalPickerDialogBody.findViewById(R.id.interval_picker_1);
} else {
    intervalPicker1 = (NumberPicker)
             intervalPickerDialogBody.findViewById(R.id.interval_picker_1);
}
```

Note 1 is that I'm making the assumption that the instanceof check won't crash at run time if the class you're checking against doesn't exist.  If it does, you'll have to reverse the order of the checks.

Comment: Thank you for this elaboration. I guess you are right. The problem is that even with your code, the app would most probably crash if the `LayoutInflater`'s bug gets fixed because my app later counts on `api11_intervalPicker1` being initialized when it's running on Honeycomb or newer... I guess I would just need a better way to use different classes with the same name on different Android versions. I will leave it like this for now, as it is an application noone will use anyway.